# InputManagerService(60): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity the I opened with:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, MapActivity.class);
activity.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

It opens and the user can work with it just fine, and in order to close it the user presses the back button. When I am trying to open this activity again with these two lines I get the following message and nothing happens, i.e. the current activity screen(different one) doesn't change to the desired one.
The error is: `08-26 19:15:53.822: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40698bb0`

please note that I am closing the activity with this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)){
        finish();
        if (mapView != null){
            mapView.clean();
            mapView = null;
        }
        if (!onRetainCalled){
            mapComponent.stopMapping();
            mapComponent = null;
        }
        Log.d("MAPA", "STOPPED!");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

i.e. when the back button is pressed the application finishes. 
I can't seem to understand why I get the warning above, and why it is not switching to the desired Intent.

Thanks.